# Not able to include Module in a Class in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class(Server) that include module(ServerConstants)

```
class Server
   include ServerConstants
```

Both files reside inside lib/server folder

I get an error : Unable to autoload constant Server::ServerConstants

1. When I use require explicitly it works fine.
2. I read about Rails Autoloading feature and wonder why it is not picking it up . My application.rb files seems to include autoload paths correctly.

   ```
   config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
   config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
   ```

What I am missing ?
We are using Rails 4.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer by Hit and Trial , although I am not sure why it worked.

Instead of defining module like

```
module ServerConstants
```

I used

```
module Server::ServerConstants
```

and it worked !

Another Finding :

This problem only occurs when you have same name of folder and class including module. In my case server folder contains both Server class and ServerConstants module. When I refactored name of Server to Server_X , the problem faded away.

Answer (score 0):

Include statement directly looks for modules defined without scope or conflicts with names. But when you place it inside lib/server/ directory, it can be access by telling `include` statement, which directory to look in to find `ServerConstants` module. That is why if you use `include Server::ServerConstants`, it works as now you have mentioned which folder to look in and now scope of the module that you want to access is now mentioned.